# Cannot install Fast debugger in Netbeans 6.8 for Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans 6.8 version and Ruby 1.9.1 installed on Windows XP. I tried to install the fast debugger and I am getting the following error.

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing
>   ruby-debug-ide:  ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> D:/Ruby19/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
>
> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while...
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   D:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9
>   for inspection.
>
> Results logged to
>   D:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/ext/gem_make.out

Have someone else faced this problem before. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WIKI link given here is broken - now can find at http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/UsingTheJRubyDebugger

Answer (score 1):

It`s a known issue, please follow instructions at: http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/Using_the_JRuby_Debugger