# Trouble in installing fast debugger on Netbeans IDE 6.9 for rails 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, netbeans-6.9, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to install the  fast debugger on netbeans IDE in ubuntu natty narwahl.I am receiving this error.How can i fix this?

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

rake RUBYARCHDIR=/home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib RUBYLIBDIR=/home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib
/home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:388:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) with executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/roger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Thanks

P.s. :I have already checked out the link [Cannot install Fast debugger in Netbeans 6.8 for Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919328/cannot-install-fast-debugger-in-netbeans-6-8-for-ruby-1-9) but i am not able to exactly comprehend how they have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

hit 'gem env' on the command line and take note of the GEM paths

(1)GO to project properties.

(2)Select Rails

(3)Click on 'Manage' button corresponding to the ruby platform

(4)Now change the gem paths  & home path provided in the netbeans IDE for gems to the one you noted before.

This would solve your problem!!